# How to drop users by mask in the Oracle RDBMS

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I want to drop all users who have 'WIN' at the start of their name (for example, 'WIN$DOWS'). Is it possible to write something like like the follownig?

```
drop user where name like 'WIN%'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The DROP USER statement doesn't support a WHERE clause, much less LIKE and wildcarding.

You need to fetch a list of users from [DBA_USERS](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4174.htm) that match, and iterate over that list:

```
--Bye Users!
FOR i IN (SELECT t.username
            FROM DBA_USERS t
           WHERE t.username LIKE 'WIN%') LOOP
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop user '|| i.username ||'';
END LOOP;
```

Comment: You might need/want to tack on `CASCADE` at the end, too

Answer (score 1):

I had an error with the solution above without the `BEGIN` .. `EXCEPTION` .. `END` syntax.
This works for me:

```
BEGIN
  FOR i IN (
    SELECT t.username
    FROM DBA_USERS t
    WHERE t.username LIKE 'WIN%') 
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP USER '|| i.username;
  END LOOP;
 EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
   dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
END;
/
```

For a cascading deletion add `|| ' CASCADE'` after `i.username`.

Answer (score 1):

In case cascade delete

```
BEGIN
  FOR i IN (
    SELECT t.username
    FROM DBA_USERS t
    WHERE t.username LIKE 'WIN%') 
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP USER '|| i.username || ' CASCADE';
  END LOOP;
 EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
   dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
END;
/
```